Autopopulate and Hide Subject line with Custom Dropdown Option
I'm trying to autopopulate the subject line from a dropdown value that the requestor would select from the form. I currently have the code below that is successfully hiding the subject field but the custom dropdown value selected isn't populating into the subject line. Nothing is actually populating. Right now this code is theoretically inputting the custom value when the Submit button is clicked. Can someone help tell me what I'm missing in my code to get this to work? this is in the script.js tab. Thank you!

//Hide Subject and auto populate with custom field dropdown selection
$(document).ready(function () {
var ticketForm = location.search.split('ticket_form_id=')[1];
var subject_value = $('.request_custom_fields_987654321').val();
if(ticketForm == 123456789) {
  $('#request_subject').parent('.request_subject').hide();
  $("#new_request").submit(function(e){
      $('#request_subject').val(subject_value);
  })
   }
})


Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] and give us a [mcve] we can look at, run and change. You can mock the ticketForm content. We want to see the RELEVANT HTML

Also if(+ticketForm === 123456789) { to test numerically and if(ticketForm.trim() === '123456789') { to test the string

@mplungjan I edited the code like you suggested in the post :)
Also, I tried what you suggested and those didn't work :(

You did NOT provider a [mcve]. Please make a snippet with the relevant HTML and frameworks so we have a running example

I have done this before.  May I ask why you are only populating the subject line on submit rather than outside of the submit event?
